# Expectation of multiplied matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

In p.50 of *Quadratic forms in random variables: theory and applications* by Mathai and Provost (1992)

> $$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}A\mathbf{X}\right]=\cdots =\mathbb{E}\left[\operatorname{tr}\left(A\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}} \right ) \right ]=\operatorname{tr}\left(A\left(\Sigma+\mathbf{\mu}\mathbf{\mu}^{\operatorname{T}} \right ) \right )$$ where $\mathbf{\mu}=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\right]$ and $\Sigma=\operatorname{cov}\left[\mathbf{X}\right]$.

(The notation has slightly changed but the meaning should be the same.)

I am having trouble with the last two steps shown above.

I understand that $$\mathbb{E}\left[\operatorname{tr}\left(A\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right)\right]=\operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[A\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right]\right)$$
but I am not sure why 
$$\operatorname{tr\left(\mathbb{E}\left[A\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right]\right)}=\operatorname{tr}\left(A\left(\Sigma+\mathbf{\mu}\mathbf{\mu}^{\operatorname{T}}\right)\right)$$

Breaking this down, the above equality is implying that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[A\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right]=A\left(\Sigma+\mathbf{\mu}\mathbf{\mu}^{\operatorname{T}}\right)$$

I understand that
$$\Sigma=\operatorname{cov}\left[\mathbf{X}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right]-\mathbf{\mu}\mathbf{\mu}^{\operatorname{T}}\Leftrightarrow\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right]=\Sigma+\mathbf{\mu}\mathbf{\mu}^{\operatorname{T}}$$

Then this is implying that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[A\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right]=A\,\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right]$$

I do not know why
$$\mathbb{E}\left[A\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right]=A\,\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\operatorname{T}}\right]$$
I would really appreciate it if anyone can provide a proof for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This follows by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), since $A$ is deterministic. In general, if $A$ is deterministic and $B$ is random (take $B=XX^\top$ in your case) we have that
$$
\mathbb E(AB)_{ik}=\mathbb E\sum_k A_{ij}B_{jk}=\sum_k A_{ij}\mathbb EB_{jk}=(A\mathbb EB)_{ik},
$$
and therefore $\mathbb EAB=A\mathbb EB$.

Comment: Hi @pre-kidney, did you mean $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(AB \right )_{ik} \right ]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j}A_{ij}B_{jk} \right ]=\sum_{j}\left(A_{ij}\mathbb{E}\left[B_{jk} \right ]\right)=\left(A\,\mathbb{E}\left[B \right ] \right )_{ik}$$? (Mainly the change in the $k$ in the summation to a $j$.)